# UIDevice Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, device-orientation

How to find out if the UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp is landscape FaceUp or Portrait FaceUp?

Can any one tell me?

Comment: Portrait and Landscape orientations make sense only in case if device's "face" is positioned orthogonal relative to Earth surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, because the accelerometer can't detect rotation around the z axis. On an iPhone 4, you could perhaps use the gyroscope for this (using CoreMotion), but `UIDevice` doesn't have an API for this. You would then also have to define what the starting position is, because you can't detect in which direction the user is from the device's point of view.

Answer (score 4):

`UIDeviceOrientation` will only tell you the orientation of the physical device. You need to use methods that use `UIInterfaceOrientation` (from `UIApplication`) to make decisions depending on whether the screen is in portrait and landscape mode.

You can use `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait()` with a `UIInterfaceOrientation` too.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a simple solution to this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly...?

Comment: So, for completeness, the example is: UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question now, but looking at the answers everyone is being overly pedantic. In case anyone else stumbles across this:

The answer to your problem is for you to keep a secondary variable which is any of your accepted orientations.

When the device orientation notification comes in, simply look at the incoming orientation and see if its an acceptable one, (portrait/landscape NOT faceup/facedown) then update your secondary variable, and finally trigger a ui/app refresh from there using your secondary variable as the orientation source.

This will have the effect of locking the orientation to the "last known good" orientation.

Answer (score 0):

UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown are orientations for when the device is laying flat (like on a table). Portrait and Landscape don't make sense in this cases.

Comment: but suppose I want to show an actionsheet which has different layouts in portrait and landscape modes. How can I ensure it is rendered properly when the user is having DeviceOrientation FaceUp or FaceDown?

Comment: can anyone tell me how to auto-adjust a UIActionsheet frame based on Device Orientation?

Comment: If you are adjusting the orientation yourself, pick one, either Landscape or Portrait. I usually ignore both faceup and face down, that way the last orientation (Landscape or Portrait) will remain when going FaceUp of FaceDown.

Comment: Now, the second comment is a different question. For the UIActionsheet to autorotate you have to present it from a ViewControler that rotates automatically.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can find out from orientation . I have found a workaround.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

if(screenBounds.size.width > screenBounds.size.height)
{
    // This means FaceUP/Down is in Landscape
}
else
{
    // This means FaceUp/Down is in Portrait
}
```